# How to set items directly to index 1 by skipping index 0 in comobox

Tags: c#, combobox

i am working on windows form application and i need to add items in my combobox but in my scenario i want to add items directly to index 1 of combobox so default index should be 1 not zero. Please help

Comment: Little bit confusing, do you want the first item to be selected in the combo or want to insert a new item to index `1`

Comment: i want to add item directly on index 1 by  leaving/ hiding / skipping index 0

i want 
Index 1: abc
index 2: asc
index 3: fgr
and so on...

i dont want my combo box start from index 0
it directly read or access data from index 1

Comment: What would doing this accomplish? Are you merely trying to represent your combo box's internal array as a one-based array?

Comment: i just want to represent my combo box start from index 1 except index 0

Comment: @MuhammadTanzeelArshad That's completely arbitrary, and I would highly recommend against it. Instead of going through the amount of difficult and tedious work it would take to recreate a combo box control that indexes its items starting from 1, I'd suggest just coming to terms with the fact that it, just like virtually every other array-based collection in C#, starts with 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of skipping index 0 in comobox you can remove it

```
myComboBox.RemoveAt(0);
```

Or You can set Directly index 1's Value

```
myComboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: it giving error value "1" is not valid selected index

Comment: waiting for the solution is anybody help me ?

Comment: refer  bellow links, 
http://net-informations.com/q/faq/combovalue.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx